# how to run xsd2json behind proxy

Tags: reactjs, proxy, prolog

I can't find documentation to specify the proxy for prolog, here is the error I'm getting :

```
xsdjs>xsd2json file.xsd > c:/xsdjs/schema.json
ERROR: -g user:main: Socket error: Connection refused
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [82] throw(error(socket_error(wsaeconnrefused,'Connection refused'),_55554))
ERROR:   [80] socket:tcp_connect('ahu.fr':443,_55598,[visited(...)]) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/library/ext/clib/socket.pl:458
ERROR:   [79] http_open:open_socket('ahu.fr':443,_55654,[visited(...)]) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/library/ext/http/http/http_open.pl:949
ERROR:   [77] http_open:try_http_proxy(direct,[uri('https://ahu.fr//v2.0.13/Format.xsd'),...|...],_55712,[]) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/library/ext/http/http/http_open.pl:475
ERROR:   [75] xsd2json:load_xsd('https://ahu.fr/mn/v2.0.13/Format.xsd',[],_55770) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:220
ERROR:   [74] xsd2json:xsd2json('https://ahu.fr/mn/v2.0.13/Format.xsd',[],_55810) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:270
ERROR:   [72] xsd2json:node___6__44__1__82([suspension(8,active,t,0,...,node_attribute,'c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',...,schemaLocation,'https://ahu.fr/mn/v2.0.13/Format.xsd',source),...|...],ns(xs,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),suspension(6,active,t,2,xsd2json: ...,node,'c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',ns(xs,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),schema,[0],[...|_55958],[]),[],'c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',ns(xs,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),import,[0,0],_55862,[0],suspension(9,active,t(...,x,-,t,t),0,xsd2json: ...,node,'c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',ns(xs,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'),import,[0|...],_56006,[0])) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:2285
ERROR:   [13] xsd2json:xsd_flatten_nodes('c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',[0],0,[element(...,...,[]),...|...],[],[[0|...]|_56122]) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:724
ERROR:   [12] xsd2json:xsd_flatten_nodes('c:/users/desktop/dev/xsd/xsd2project/xsdjs/file.xsd',[],0,[element(...,...,...)],[],[[0]]) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:729
ERROR:   [11] xsd2json:xsd2json('file.xsd',[space(remove),...|...],_56240) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/xsd2json.pl:274
ERROR:   [10] main([space(remove),...|...],['file.xsd']) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/lib-pl/cli.pl:121
ERROR:    [8] catch(user:main,error(socket_error(wsaeconnrefused,'Connection refused'),context(_56366,_56368)),'$toplevel':true) at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/boot/init.pl:564
ERROR:    [7] catch_with_backtrace('<garbage_collected>','<garbage_collected>','<garbage_collected>') at c:/users/appdata/roaming/npm/node_modules/xsd2json/boot/init.pl:644
ERROR:
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```